# Cursor disappears intermittently, always after opening System Settings

Tags: cursor

Similar questions have been asked, I admit. I have just done a fresh, new install of ALWAYS disappears when I open System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that was posted by [Eric Doriean](https://askubuntu.com/users/346731/eric-doriean) for a similar question. In System Settings / Displays I found that I had an "Unknown Display" that was "On" as well as my "Built-in Display". I clicked on the "Unknown Display" graphic, then I clicked on the ON/OFF toggle, to turn off the "Unknown Display". After that my cursor problems went away.